# Where do I ask about finding an example in fiction of a parent-child team?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about locating an example of a particular trope in fiction:

> Are there any examples of fiction featuring a parent and their child (especially main characters) working together as a team? It would be similar to a [Sibling Team](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SiblingTeam) (TVTropes definition in link), except that the specific familial relationship would be different. I have searched on the Internet, but I have not been able to find examples of this. I am not talking about an entire family working together (there are many examples of that in fiction), but just one parent-child duo.

Now, I haven't been able to find which specific site I should post this question on. I would accept any fictional work, not just sci-fi/fantasy, that has an example of this as an answer, so I don't think the question would fit on Science Fiction and Fantasy, and as it is about existing works, it probably would't work on Writers either. I just can't find the site where I could ask this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're interested in fictional **written** works, ask on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). They probably cover plays, too. If you're interested in fictional **on-screen** works, ask on [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Be aware, though, that "I am building a list, please give me one answer for each possible member of my list" is not a good question for these sites. You could ask "has there ever been one example of" "what was the first use of" or "is this as common a trope as" or "how can I find examples of" - but don't ask for a list.

Comment: (We do cover plays. And poetry. And song lyrics.) But this type of question may not be so well received.

Comment: @Mithrandir can you guide the OP to a formulation of something that is askable and answerable and might lead to the OP gaining the required information?

Comment: I'm not sure. Something like 'what is the first instance of a duo like this', tagged [history-of-literature], might work.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say it would be much too broad - you're essentially asking for a list of *all the possible works* that fit a very broad 'trope' or theme. '

Now a *few* sites don't mind *identification* type questions when trying to find *specific works*.

However I'm pretty doubtful this question would be "practically answerable" and probably isn't a good fit for the format here.